# 'option<unit->unit> type and the equality' using F#

Tags: function, f#, option-type

Consider the following code:

```
let fnOption = Some (fun () -> ())
fnOption = None
```

It gives the following error:

> init.fsx(2,1): error FS0001: The type '(unit -> unit)' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a function type

Why is that? Did I overlook something?

Comment: Functions are first class values in FP but they are special types of values in the sense that they are used to produce other values based on the parameters u pass to them, hence it doesn't make sense to compare 2 functions and as a consequence there is no equality operator  defined for functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted to check for equality (and not to assign the value), then you can use `Option.isNone fnOption`. If you really do want to assign, look as kvb's answer.

Comment: That is true. I did not notice this function. So does that mean that F# tries to do a structural equality? But then again it could immediately see that Some XXX <> None and did not even have to check what is inside.

Comment: The error is during compile-time, not run-time. F# compiler **tries** to compile the code, but fails, because `The type '(unit -> unit)' does not support the 'equality' constraint`. On dynamic languages (without pre-compilation type checks), it might have worked with structural equality.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you're trying to do.  As it stands, the second line is an *equality test*, not an *assignment*.  If what you intended to do was assign a new value to `fnOption`, then you need to make it mutable:

```
let mutable fnOption = Some(fun () -> ())
fnOption <- None
```

If you are really trying to test equality, then the error you are seeing is the expected result, because functions aren't comparable.

Comment: The functions are not comparable but options are, right? I can do: `let a = Some 4; a = None`

Comment: can he use Some id instead of Some (fun () -> ())?

Comment: @Alex - no, values of function types are not comparable, so neither are options containing functions (regardless of what the actual values are).  Even `(None : (unit -> unit) option) = None` will not compile because the compiler doesn't "look inside" the option value; the determination of whether the values can be compared is made solely based on their types.